# Error in when Python Class make

Tags: python

**Code :**

```
class calculator:

    def addition(x,y):
        add = x + y
        print (add)

    def subtraction(x,y):
        sub = x - y
        print (sub)

    def multiplication(x,y):
        mul = x * y
        print (mul)

    def division(x,y):
        div = x / y
        print (div)

calculator.division(100,4)
calculator.multiplication(22,4)
calculator.subtraction(20,2)
calculator.addition(10,3)
```

when I run this code is gives Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "calculator.py", line 19, in
>   
>       calculator.division(100,4) TypeError: unbound method division() must be called with calculator instance as first argument (got int
>   instance instead)

I am learning Python so can anyone solve this error.

Comment: you forgot to put `self` as the first argument in each function definition.. https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/

Comment: also, you need to invoke an instance of the class before calling the methods.

Comment: @Farhan.K can you modified my code

Comment: thanks @James actually i don't know more about python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.  First, you create a class, but you never instantiate an instance of that class.  Such as:

```
class Calculator:
    ...
    ...

calculator = Calculator()
```

Second, methods called from an object always accept the object itself as the first argument.  That is why you see `self` in the definition of methods.  Even if you don't use `self`, it is still implicitly passed as the first argument.

```
class Calculator:

    def addition(self, x, y):
        add = x + y
        print(add)

    def subtraction(self, x, y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    def multiplication(self, x, y):
        mul = x * y
        print(mul)

    def division(self, x, y):
        div = x / y
        print(div)


calculator = Calculator()
```

Comment: no problem.  please mark the question as answered (the check mark)

Answer (score 1):

You can either make your functions static with `@staticmethod` (so you can call them without creating an instance)

```
class Calculator:
    @staticmethod
    def addition(x, y):
        add = x + y
        print(add)

Calculator.addition(10, 3)
```

or you add `self` as an argument and create an instance of `Calculator`.

```
class Calculator:
    def addition(self, x, y):
        add = x + y
        print(add)

calc = Calculator()
calc.addition(10, 3)
```